# Spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-post, get-request

I recently started learning about Spring-Boot but I'm stuck in the middle of something.
the GitHub link is right here fr the complete project https://github.com/Timmy1505/springbooy-app.git
I have a rest controller that I want to change to a controller and render thymeleaf templates (registration_form) and post the request

Code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService;

    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "confirm")
    public String confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having doing that?

Comment: I want to render the HTML page for sign up and perform the request

Answer (score 1):

Change `@RestController` to `@Controller` to support view rendering.

Comment: yes, thank you. but I want the registration_form.htm in my templates package to be rendered and perform the action. I have tested it using postman to post requests and it's working just fine.